# How I migrate from laravel to my database

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I'm trying to create a migration to add tables and columns to my database and all I get is this error.

*PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CreateJuegosTable, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\2020-21-DAW2-M12-Royal-Dice\database\migrations\2021_05_10_000000_create_juegos.php on line 7*

this is the code I'm trying to run:

> ```
>   <?php
>
> use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
> use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
>
> class CreateJuegosTable extends Migration
> {
>     /**
>      * Run the migrations.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function up()
>     {
>         Schema::create('juegos', function (Blueprint $table) {
>             $table->id();
>             $table->string('juego');
>         });
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Reverse the migrations.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function down()
>     {
>         Schema::dropIfExists('juegos');
>     }
> }
> ```

[This is the file names, I changed and the error still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBxZV.png)

This is the model

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: That error is very specific and is telling you exactly what the problem is. You have already defined that class in the location specified. You either need to delete/rename the existing one, or rename this one.

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: I have to rename it even if the database is empty?

Comment: At this point, it's nothing to do with the database, this is a PHP error. Is saying that a class already exists called `CreateJuegosTable`. I would imagine that you've already created a migration for this table.

Comment: So if I did a previous migrate of this class even if i deleted it from the database i have to rename the class?

Comment: Yes. As previously mentioned, this has nothing to do with the database itself. There are 2 PHP files inside of the migrations folder that have the `CreateJuegosTable` defined. Delete the old one, or rename the new one, or if you're trying to change your definition, just modify the old one.

Comment: I renamed all the folders and it shows me the same error message. I have no clue of what can i do.

Comment: What files do you have in `database/migrations`?

Comment: I added the pic to the question

Comment: Open each one and check what the _class names_ are. You cannot have any duplicates. Rename them if they're duplicated.

Comment: Yes I know and tried everything trust me. but somehow the error persists

Answer (score 0):

check migrations and rename if any exists with the name "Juegos". if refactor/rename does not work open the migration and rename directly.... then run below command to clear cache

```
php artisan optimize
```

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateJuegosTable---(rename this)---- extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('juegos'---(rename this)----, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('juego');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('juegos'----(rename this)----);
    }
}
```

Comment: I renamed it several times and also tried the php artisan optimize, I don't know why but it keeps showing me the same message.

Comment: can we see your role model?

Comment: and also the renamed migrations.

Comment: Yes I will add it to the question